# Using ENTER key to submit default Drupal 7 Search doesn't not return results: Why?

Tags: 7, forms, search

I have a design provided by the customer, where the search block form has no SUBMIT button. It is expected the user just hits the "enter" key.

Users can type keywords into the search box, and when they press "enter," the form is submitted. The problem is that the form is submitted always with "#default_value" and never with the keywords typed into the input box.

On the advanced search page/results the search does work.

Does anyone know why this might be?

We have hidden the submit button via a CSS call of `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `<form>`'s submit event rather than the `<input>`'s click event to respond to the form submission? Check out [this working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHGW8/).

```
$("#form").bind('submit', function(e) {
    var $div = $("<div>Transmitting</div>").appendTo('body');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax_html_echo/',
        data: {html: $("#html").val() },
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $div.html("Received: "+data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```